# marklogic rest api extension output content-type

Tags: rest, marklogic

I try to write a GET service for media.

When I upload the media file, I use `xdmp:document-filter` to store in the property of the file the meta information like the *content-type*.
In the GET, I read in this property file and try to put it in the header of the reply.

```
   let $propertiesHtml := xdmp:document-get-properties($uri,fn:QName("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","html"))
    let $content-type := $propertiesHtml/*/*:meta[@name='content-type']/@content/string()
    let $_ := map:put($context, "output-type", $content-type)
```

When I test with Postman, the *content-type* is always: `application/x-unknown-content-type`
and not `image/jpeg` as it should be (I trace it in the log file).

I read the documentation but I understand how to do that.

I test if the file is an XML one, application/xml is set

Comment: Is your code in a REST extension as defined at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions ?

Comment: Take some time to troubleshoot line by line.. Are You sure Your property is stored? Are You sure that it was retrieved properly and that $content-type actually has a value?  I mention this because if $content-type is empty, then "output-type is empty" as well. This would end up returning "unknown" for the content-type..

Comment: Yes, I use ml-gradle to deploy my rest extension.
Yes I verify this using xdmp:log before

Comment: I think it's a very simple problem, because nothing runs in the headers.
I write a very simple extension get :
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace he.test = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/he.test";

declare function he.test:get($context as map:map,$params as map:map) as document-node() {
    let $doc := doc('/LS/MEDIA/test')
    let $_ := map:put($context, "output-type",'image/jpeg')
    let $_ := map:put($context,"ouput-headers",("Marc","value1","marc2","value2"))
return
$doc
};
and I always have the application/x-unknown-content-type and no specific headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the typo of output-type -> output-types with a "s", plural but I don't know why!
This is an error in the documentation